# django "is a manually-defined m2m relation through model...which does not have foreign keys to"

Tags: django, python-3.x, m2m

There have been some close ones on this, but all I can find is what I'm doing and its not working.

Here is an example: You have a product which can have multiple options.  Each option can have multiple choices.

```
class Option_Choices(models.Model):
    """
    choices for each option
    """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Product_Options(models.Model):
    """
    products can have many options
    """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    option_type = models.IntegerField(choices=OPTION_TYPE)
    choices = models.ManyToManyField(Option_Choices, related_name='product_options_choices')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Product(models.Model):
    """
    there are options for products - different sizes / colors
    """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    options = models.ManyToManyField(Product_Options, related_name='product_options')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Looks simple enough, I get this error

> 'options' is a manually-defined m2m relation through model
>   Product_Options, which does not have foreign keys to Product_Options
>   and Product

I've tried a ton of different things, including using "through" can't figure out why this isn't working.  its what everyone says to do.  any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually reverse m2m definitions as below. In your code above you're seeing a conflict in table names due to the underscore in your model class names. If you **remove the underscores** it should work.

Reversing the relationships could work if you want to keep the underscores.

```
class Option_Choices(models.Model):
    """
    choices for each option
    """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    product_options = models.ManyToManyField("Product_Options", related_name='choices')


class Product_Options(models.Model):
    """
    products can have many options
    """
    OPTION_TYPE=(
        ('Color', 1),
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    option_type = models.IntegerField(choices=OPTION_TYPE)
    products = models.ManyToManyField("Product", related_name='options')


class Product(models.Model):
    """
    there are options for products - different sizes / colors
    """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Comment: "Reversing" the M2M relationship is wrong. See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/)

Comment: @hobs Could you elaborate?

Comment: I misunderstood what you meant by "reverse". I thought you were reversing the direction of the relationships by putting FK fields in opposite tables and I didn't scroll far enough to the right to see that you hadn't defined Option_Choices as an explicit `through` model. Can't put M2M's in a through table... but you haven't, so you're OK.  That's what I get for skimming.